# How to override blog template generator (article.tt) in Middleman Blog Gem?

Tags: middleman

The middleman blog gem creates new articles based on `lib/middleman-blog/commands/article.tt` Current format is is;

```
---
title: <%= @title %>
date: <%= @date.strftime('%F %R %Z') %>
tags:
---
```

What is the best way to override that if I wanted default front matter to be something else like;

```
---
layout: blog
author: Dave
---
```

*(Other than opening the gem and changing it there.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding `blog.new_article_template` to blog settings in `config.rb` like so

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.prefix = 'blog' 
  blog.new_article_template = 'source/blog/template.erb'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to override that.

But probably you could find where in Middleman Blog code that file is invoked and override that method from `config.rb`, having it pointing at a different template file.